# SQL grouping by one value in 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL grouping by one value in 2 columns

```
Source data table:

  P2  P3
----------
   1   2
   2   1
   2   3
   4   1
```

I want a query that counts a's and b's in each column, producing something like:

```
num  conut
-------------
1 3
2 3
3 1
4 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `union all` and `group by`:

```
select num, sum(cnt) as conut
from (select p2 as num, count(*) as cnt from source group by p2
      union all
      select p3 as num, count(*) as cnt from source group by p3
     ) p
group by num;
```

Comment: need edit in second select : `select p3 as num, count(*) as cnt from source group by p3`

Comment: @user2315555 . . . Actually, you don't need the aliases after the first subquery.  It did, however, need a comma.